# Why does visual studio not repaint the program when I click on certain places like the solution explorer tab?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I managed to get VS2013 in this strange state a couple times now: The program loads fine but when I click on the solution explorer tab, the error list tab and a few others the program won't repaint in response to my click. I have to minimize the program and remaximize, whereupon everything appears as it should have right after the click.

I don't know if anyone had this issue before.. if not, where can I file a bug report?

Comment: I also noticed this bug. Only appears if a move the mouse over Solution Explorer items, or press [Windows key] + D two times

Comment: To report this BUG you can go to http://connect.microsoft.com/

Comment: I think we got spoiled by the infrequent visual studio releases of the past. There were hardly any bugs like this. Now we're at the bleeding (and buggy) edge all the time.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/832165/sometimes-the-solution-explorer-team-explorer-error-list-output-area-and-many-others-wont-repaint-when-clicked-on-under-hardware-acceleration

Comment: @Tony should should go vote for my bug in the link above.\

Answer (score 0):

I changed back to software rendering, it worked properly immediately. I was using 3d acceleration.